# How to prevent screen from going black (back light is shut down) at startup (laptop) Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, startup, backlight

So,in may laptop with Ubuntu 12.04, the startup is like this:

1) I see the Ubuntu logo with the 5 dots on a purple background for a few seconds.

2) The screen goes completely black (no back light), but it's not shut down, i can still see shadows.

3) The system is fully loaded (i can log-in), but the screen is still shadowy (no back light).

4) I have to wait about 1 minute (logged or not) for the back light to turn on.

How do I prevent the system from shutting the back light at startup ?

Answer (score 1):

Open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run this command to open GRUB's main configuration file in `nano` (a non-graphical text editor):

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

In the text editor, find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Add `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the end, so it looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save the file and quit the text editor, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>. Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Done.  Backlight will be at full strength by default.